# Python Recursive Tensorflow Fibonacci Number Calculation

Tags: python, recursion, tensorflow

I'm new to tensorflow and I was trying to write a tensorflow program which calculates a fibonacci number recursively.  The following program is what I ended up with but it fails with many errors which I don't understand.  Can someone help me understand what I'm doing wrong and how to fix it.  Here is my program:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.ERROR)

with tf.Graph().as_default() as g:
    fib_seed_0 = tf.Variable(0, name = "fib_seed_0")
    fib_seed_1 = tf.Variable(1, name = "fib_seed_1")

    def fib(n):
        return tf.cond(tf.equal(n, fib_seed_0), lambda: tf.identity(n),
       lambda: tf.cond(tf.equal(n, fib_seed_1), lambda: tf.identity(n),
       lambda: tf.add(fib(tf.subtract(n, 1)), fib(tf.subtract(n, 2)))))

    fib_to_calc = tf.Variable(5, name = "fib_to_calc")

    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(init)
        print(sess.run(fib(fib_to_calc)))
```

Here is what the above tensorflow program is trying to do in a python translation:

```
def F(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    elif n == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return F(n-1) + F(n-2)
```

Here is a sample of the error log.  It goes on and on and on:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\IronKey\DeveloperTools\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\control_flow_ops.py", line 1775, in cond
    return merges[0] if len(merges) == 1 else merges
  File "C:\IronKey\DeveloperTools\Anaconda3\lib\contextlib.py", line 77, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "C:\IronKey\DeveloperTools\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 4169, in name_scope
    yield scope
  File "C:\IronKey\DeveloperTools\Anaconda3\lib\contextlib.py", line 77, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "C:\IronKey\DeveloperTools\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 3625, in get_controller
    yield default
  File "C:\IronKey\DeveloperTools\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 4169, in name_scope
    yield scope
  File "C:\IronKey\DeveloperTools\Anaconda3\lib\contextlib.py", line 77, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "C:\IronKey\DeveloperTools\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 2860, in name_scope
    yield "" if new_stack is None else new_stack + "/"
  File "C:\IronKey\DeveloperTools\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 4169, in name_scope
    yield scope
  File "C:\IronKey\DeveloperTools\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\control_flow_ops.py", line 1748, in cond
    _, res_f = context_f.BuildCondBranch(fn2)
  File "C:\IronKey\DeveloperTools\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\control_flow_ops.py", line 1642, in BuildCondBranch
    r = fn()
  File "fib.py", line 13, in <lambda>
    lambda: tf.add(fib(tf.subtract(n, 1)), fib(tf.subtract(n, 2)))))
  File "fib.py", line 12, in fib
    lambda: tf.cond(tf.equal(n, fib_seed_1), lambda: tf.identity(n),
  File "C:\IronKey\DeveloperTools\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\control_flow_ops.py", line 1775, in cond
    return merges[0] if len(merges) == 1 else merges
  File "C:\IronKey\DeveloperTools\Anaconda3\lib\contextlib.py", line 77, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "C:\IronKey\DeveloperTools\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 4169, in name_scope
    yield scope
  File "C:\IronKey\DeveloperTools\Anaconda3\lib\contextlib.py", line 77, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "C:\IronKey\DeveloperTools\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 3625, in get_controller
    yield default
  File "C:\IronKey\DeveloperTools\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 4169, in name_scope
    yield scope
  File "C:\IronKey\DeveloperTools\Anaconda3\lib\contextlib.py", line 77, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "C:\IronKey\DeveloperTools\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 2860, in name_scope
    yield "" if new_stack is None else new_stack + "/"
  File "C:\IronKey\DeveloperTools\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 4169, in name_scope
    yield scope
  File "C:\IronKey\DeveloperTools\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\control_flow_ops.py", line 1748, in cond
    _, res_f = context_f.BuildCondBranch(fn2)
  File "C:\IronKey\DeveloperTools\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\control_flow_ops.py", line 1642, in BuildCondBranch
```

... 
The above error repeats many times then the following errors come out
...

```
    r = fn()
  File "fib.py", line 12, in <lambda>
    lambda: tf.cond(tf.equal(n, fib_seed_1), lambda: tf.identity(n),
  File "C:\IronKey\DeveloperTools\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_array_ops.py", line 1343, in identity
    result = _op_def_lib.apply_op("Identity", input=input, name=name)
  File "C:\IronKey\DeveloperTools\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py", line 777, in apply_op
    return op
  File "C:\IronKey\DeveloperTools\Anaconda3\lib\contextlib.py", line 77, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "C:\IronKey\DeveloperTools\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 3625, in get_controller
    yield default
  File "C:\IronKey\DeveloperTools\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py", line 777, in apply_op
    return op
  File "C:\IronKey\DeveloperTools\Anaconda3\lib\contextlib.py", line 77, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "C:\IronKey\DeveloperTools\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 4169, in name_scope
    yield scope
  File "C:\IronKey\DeveloperTools\Anaconda3\lib\contextlib.py", line 77, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "C:\IronKey\DeveloperTools\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 3625, in get_controller
    yield default
  File "C:\IronKey\DeveloperTools\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 4169, in name_scope
    yield scope
  File "C:\IronKey\DeveloperTools\Anaconda3\lib\contextlib.py", line 77, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "C:\IronKey\DeveloperTools\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 2860, in name_scope
    yield "" if new_stack is None else new_stack + "/"
  File "C:\IronKey\DeveloperTools\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 4169, in name_scope
    yield scope
  File "C:\IronKey\DeveloperTools\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py", line 777, in apply_op
    return op
  File "C:\IronKey\DeveloperTools\Anaconda3\lib\contextlib.py", line 77, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "C:\IronKey\DeveloperTools\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py", line 255, in _MaybeColocateWith
    yield
  File "C:\IronKey\DeveloperTools\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py", line 768, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "C:\IronKey\DeveloperTools\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 2336, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "C:\IronKey\DeveloperTools\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1232, in __init__
    self._control_flow_context.AddOp(self)
  File "C:\IronKey\DeveloperTools\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\control_flow_ops.py", line 1598, in AddOp
    self._AddOpInternal(op)
  File "C:\IronKey\DeveloperTools\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\control_flow_ops.py", line 1613, in _AddOpInternal
    real_x = self.AddValue(x)
  File "C:\IronKey\DeveloperTools\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\control_flow_ops.py", line 1587, in AddValue
    result = _SwitchRefOrTensor(result, self._pred)[self._branch]
  File "C:\IronKey\DeveloperTools\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\control_flow_ops.py", line 364, in _SwitchRefOrTensor
    return switch(data, pred, name=name)
  File "C:\IronKey\DeveloperTools\Anaconda3\lib\contextlib.py", line 77, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "C:\IronKey\DeveloperTools\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 2974, in colocate_with
    yield
  File "C:\IronKey\DeveloperTools\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\control_flow_ops.py", line 364, in _SwitchRefOrTensor
    return switch(data, pred, name=name)
  File "C:\IronKey\DeveloperTools\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\control_flow_ops.py", line 320, in switch
    sparse_tensor.SparseTensor(ind_t, val_t, dense_shape_t))
  File "C:\IronKey\DeveloperTools\Anaconda3\lib\contextlib.py", line 77, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "C:\IronKey\DeveloperTools\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 4169, in name_scope
    yield scope
  File "C:\IronKey\DeveloperTools\Anaconda3\lib\contextlib.py", line 77, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "C:\IronKey\DeveloperTools\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 3625, in get_controller
    yield default
  File "C:\IronKey\DeveloperTools\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 4169, in name_scope
    yield scope
  File "C:\IronKey\DeveloperTools\Anaconda3\lib\contextlib.py", line 77, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "C:\IronKey\DeveloperTools\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 2860, in name_scope
    yield "" if new_stack is None else new_stack + "/"
  File "C:\IronKey\DeveloperTools\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 4169, in name_scope
    yield scope
  File "C:\IronKey\DeveloperTools\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\control_flow_ops.py", line 299, in switch
    return gen_control_flow_ops._switch(data, pred, name=name)
  File "C:\IronKey\DeveloperTools\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_control_flow_ops.py", line 371, in _switch
    result = _op_def_lib.apply_op("Switch", data=data, pred=pred, name=name)
  File "C:\IronKey\DeveloperTools\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py", line 777, in apply_op
    return op
  File "C:\IronKey\DeveloperTools\Anaconda3\lib\contextlib.py", line 77, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "C:\IronKey\DeveloperTools\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 3625, in get_controller
    yield default
  File "C:\IronKey\DeveloperTools\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py", line 777, in apply_op
    return op
  File "C:\IronKey\DeveloperTools\Anaconda3\lib\contextlib.py", line 77, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "C:\IronKey\DeveloperTools\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 4169, in name_scope
    yield scope
  File "C:\IronKey\DeveloperTools\Anaconda3\lib\contextlib.py", line 77, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "C:\IronKey\DeveloperTools\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 3625, in get_controller
    yield default
  File "C:\IronKey\DeveloperTools\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 4169, in name_scope
    yield scope
  File "C:\IronKey\DeveloperTools\Anaconda3\lib\contextlib.py", line 77, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "C:\IronKey\DeveloperTools\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 2860, in name_scope
    yield "" if new_stack is None else new_stack + "/"
  File "C:\IronKey\DeveloperTools\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 4169, in name_scope
    yield scope
  File "C:\IronKey\DeveloperTools\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py", line 777, in apply_op
    return op
  File "C:\IronKey\DeveloperTools\Anaconda3\lib\contextlib.py", line 77, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "C:\IronKey\DeveloperTools\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py", line 255, in _MaybeColocateWith
    yield
  File "C:\IronKey\DeveloperTools\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py", line 768, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "C:\IronKey\DeveloperTools\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 2336, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "C:\IronKey\DeveloperTools\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1180, in __init__
    if node_def.ByteSize() >= (1 << 31) or node_def.ByteSize() < 0:
  File "C:\IronKey\DeveloperTools\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\internal\python_message.py", line 1012, in ByteSize
    size += field_descriptor._sizer(field_value)
  File "C:\IronKey\DeveloperTools\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\internal\encoder.py", line 359, in FieldSize
    entry_msg = message_type._concrete_class(key=key, value=value)
  File "C:\IronKey\DeveloperTools\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\internal\python_message.py", line 511, in init
    copy = field._default_constructor(self)
  File "C:\IronKey\DeveloperTools\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\internal\python_message.py", line 423, in MakeSubMessageDefault
    result = message_type._concrete_class()
  File "C:\IronKey\DeveloperTools\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\internal\python_message.py", line 480, in init
    self._listener_for_children = _Listener(self)
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.

Comment: Can you post your error log at least?

Comment: @Prune I'm not sure what's not minimal, complete, and verifiable.  The program is only a few lines and is the entire runnable program.

Comment: You're missing the error log.

Comment: @Prune As per your recommendation I posted a sample from the error log.

Comment: Good start.  It looks like a single error log, with the problem buried under dozens of calls.  Does the last entry refer to your code?  If so, please add the last couple of lines from this stack, so we know what in *your* code caused the problem.  I don't have access to my TF environment this week to help from there, but I hope that others can help you.

Comment: @Prune I updated the errors and added the tail end of the error log.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Yuck.  It looks like you're somehow caught in an infinite loop of error handling.  I'm afraid we'll have to wait for someone versed in TF internals.

Comment: Your code ends in an endless loop even on input n=1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TensorFlow does not support recursive calls to [`tf.cond()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/cond), because its implementation eagerly calls each of the two `lambda` functions that you pass for the two branches (to build the symbolic graphs), and the termination condition is not known at graph building time, so it will recurse until you run out of stack space.

There is experimental support for defining (possibly recursive) functions in TensorFlow, using the [`tensorflow.python.framework.function`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/framework/function.py) library which is not currently part of the public API. The support for recursive functions is rudimentary, but you can define one using an explicit forward declaration, as follows:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.framework import function

fib = function.Declare("Fib", [("n", tf.int32)], [("ret", tf.int32)])

@function.Defun(tf.int32, func_name="Fib", out_names=["ret"])
def FibImpl(n):
  return tf.cond(tf.less_equal(n, 1), 
                 lambda: tf.constant(1),
                 lambda: fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2))

FibImpl.add_to_graph(tf.get_default_graph())

n = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[])
result = fib(n)

sess = tf.Session()
print(sess.run(result, feed_dict={n: 0}))  # 1
print(sess.run(result, feed_dict={n: 1}))  # 1
print(sess.run(result, feed_dict={n: 2}))  # 2
print(sess.run(result, feed_dict={n: 3}))  # 3
print(sess.run(result, feed_dict={n: 4}))  # 5
print(sess.run(result, feed_dict={n: 5}))  # 8
print(sess.run(result, feed_dict={n: 20}))  # 10946
```

Of course, an iterative solution using [`tf.while_loop()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/while_loop) would be much more efficient!